# Row deletion doesn't update table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, realm

I am loading data into a UITableViewController, the data is coming from Realm. So I have a property on my ViewController: `var nextWeekPlants: Results<Plant>!`.

The variable is loaded like this: `nextWeekPlants = realm.objects(Plant.self).filter("...")` in the `updateUI()` method I wrote. The `updateUI()` method also calls `tableView.reloadData()`.

In my `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate method, I have this check:

```
if let plants = nextWeekPlants {
    return plants.count
} else {
    return 0
}
```

Alright, it works fine collecting the data, showing it on the screen, but as soon as I remove 1 plant from the table view and want to delete another: it crashes.
`'RLMException', reason: 'Index 1 is out of bounds (must be less than 1)'`

I delete a plant in this way:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
do {
    self.realm.beginWrite()
    self.realm.delete(self.nextWeekPlants[indexPath.row])
    try self.realm.commitWrite()
} catch (let error) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

It deletes one plant just fine, but it doesn't delete the other. Do I have to update the tableView in a different way (call `updateUI()` maybe?) or do I need to update my Realm collection?

** EDIT **

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Little hack to show no extra cells and to make sure the swiping works.
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = false
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    updateUI()
}

func updateUI() {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let maxDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: Date())

    if let nextWeek = maxDate {
         nextWeekPlants = realm.objects(Plant.self).filter("nextWater <= %@", nextWeek)
    }

    self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: try reloadData() before you end updates, also remove that object from nextWeekPlants

Comment: @jbehrens94 I guess you need to update table array value as well. The plants array.

Comment: @RJiryes That will update the tableView two times, which isn't great UI, I suppose.

@TusharSharma So maybe I need to call `updateUI()` again, because that method sets the realm collection property?

Comment: May you please add the code where you call `updateUI()`?

Comment: Yes actually, just update the nextWeekPlants property :-)

Comment: @jbehrens94 I mean when you delete one row then delete that object from table array.If updateUI does that go for it.

Comment: Updated my code, @MoeAbdul-Hameed

Comment: @TusharSharma The `updateUI()` method doesn't do that really, that's maybe something I need to refactor. Move `tableView.reloadData()` to `viewWillAppear()`?

Comment: @jbehrens94 maybe you should just have another function that deletes a specific object from the property you have, and call that when you delete it from Realm and before you delete the cell.

Comment: So in what order would I do that?

`tableView.beginUpdates(); do { // remove from realm }; tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .left); self.updateUI(); tableView.endUpdates()`?

I'm not really sure what order I should follow.

Comment: @jbehrens94 The time when you delete a row at same time delete same index value from array and then call reload table.

Comment: `tableView.beginUpdates();` `do { // remove from realm };`  `self.deleteObjectFromNextWeekPlants();` `tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .left);` `tableView.endUpdates()`

Comment: Damn, the bug is still happening. As I understand it, when I remove the second plant, the indexPath.row isn't 0 but 1 and Realm then only has a Plant model at index 0.

So isn't the tableView doing something strange here?

Comment: By the way, might be part of the problem, the removal code is executed in the callback of a cell action. So I set `cell.rightButtons = ...`

Comment: @RJiryes Any idea?

Comment: @jbehrens94 it is as simple as that row deletion won't update your table but deletion of that same index value from array and calling reload data will.

Comment: Calling `reloadData()` definitely stops the crash, unfortunately I lose the nice little animation `deleteRows()` gives.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're mutating UITableView state without letting Realm know about it. Please refer to the [Interface-Driven Writes](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#interface-driven-writes) section of Realm's documentation.

```
do {
    self.realm.beginWrite()
    self.realm.delete(self.nextWeekPlants[indexPath.row])
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
    try self.realm.commitWrite(withoutNotifying: [token])
} catch (let error) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```